# CALayer does not respect zero shadowRadius while drawing?

Tags: ios, cocoa, calayer, shadow

It seems that `CALayer`'s property `shadowRadius` is non-zero while drawing even if explicitelly set to zero when following conditions are met:

1. `shadowPath` property is also set on the same `CALayer`, and
2. `shadowPath` set is something else than plain rectangular path

To reproduce the issue I created 2 rounded `CALayers` with shadow that are identical in everything but shadow path - first one has `shadowPath` set to `nil`, second one has `shadowPath` set to its own shape. I would expect those 2 to render into exactly the same picture but they do not. Here is the result (magnified):

[image]

As you can see second rectangle obviously has some shadow radius higher then 0 even though it was set to 0. Here is code used to produce the picture above:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let layerWithoutShadowPath = CALayer() //shadow of this rectangle will be drawn correctly
    let layerWithShadowPath = CALayer() //shadow of this one will be drawn with radius higher then 0

    layerWithoutShadowPath.frame = CGRect(x: 30, y: 30, width: 30, height: 30)
    layerWithShadowPath.frame = CGRect(x: 70, y: 30, width: 30, height: 30)

    layerWithShadowPath.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: layerWithShadowPath.bounds, cornerRadius: 4.0).CGPath
    setupLayer(layerWithoutShadowPath)
    setupLayer(layerWithShadowPath)
}

private func setupLayer(layer: CALayer) {
    layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(1).CGColor
    layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
    layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 3)
    layer.shadowRadius = 0  //SHADOW RADIUS IS SET TO 0 FOR BOTH RECTANGLES
    layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    view.layer.addSublayer(layer)
}
```

This might be a Cocoa bug or I am just missing something... Anyway, the question is: **How can add rounded rectangle shadow with exactly zero radius to `CALayer` while `shadowPath` is set?** (if you are wondering why I must set `shadowPath` [the reason is performance](http://angelolloqui.com/blog/30-iOS-Performance-tips-I-Drawing-shadows))

Comment: My guess is that `.shadowPath` also sets `.shouldRasterize` to `true` in which case  `.rasterizationScale` should be set to `UIScreen.mainScreen().scale`.

Comment: @fluidsonic I am afraid that's wrong guess. Just tested it setting `.rasterizationScale` to screen scale but the result is the same. My guess would be that when `.shadowPath` is set than shadow radius used is for some reason maximum of default shadow radius (3 points) and actual value of `.shadowRadius`

Comment: You lost me. The first drawing looks great so what's the problem?

Comment: @matt The first drawing (on the left) is what I want, the second (on the right) is what I get instead. The left drawing is rendered without setting `.shadowPath`. But I must set this property to avoid performance issues (tested: Frame rate to half). [Explicitelly setting `.shadowPath` to non-`nil` value improves performance significantly.](http://angelolloqui.com/blog/30-iOS-Performance-tips-I-Drawing-shadows) The problem is that with `.shadowPath` set to non-`nil` value I never get left drawing, only right. Theoretically, I should get left drawing if I set `.shadowPath` to...

Comment: @matt ...the relief (rounded rectangle in this case) of layer having the shadow. Unfortunatelly and very strangely it does not work. The reason seems to be that when `.shadowPath` is set to non-`nil` value of different property `.shadowRadius` is not zero even if I explitely set it to zero.

Comment: @matt Please let me know if the question is hard to understand, I will edit it. Please try to specify what is confusing. I really need this solved, willing to spend all my reputation on bounties if it gets me solution.

Comment: "The first drawing (on the left) is what I want" The way that I would achieve that is to draw the yellow square _and its shadow_ into a layer / view. That way you do not have the inefficiency of setting a layer's shadow, because the shadow is part of the _drawing_, not imposed in real time by the render tree. Do you see?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you *might* be able to fix it by setting the layer's `edgeAntialiasingMask`. However, it seems to me that you are needlessly trapped in a world of layer inefficiency - as if the only thing you knew how to do was make the layer draw itself with rounded corners and a shadow. What *I* would do is *draw* the yellow rounded square *and its shadow* as an actual *drawing*, and make that drawing the *content* of a layer:

```
let layer = CALayer()
layer.contentsScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
layer.frame = CGRect(x: 30, y: 30, width: 30, height: 35)
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.bounds.size, false, 0)
let con = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
CGContextSetShadowWithColor(con, CGSizeMake(0,3), 1, UIColor.blackColor().CGColor)
let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRectMake(0,0,30,30), cornerRadius: 4)
UIColor.yellowColor().setFill()
path.fill()
let im = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
layer.contents = im.CGImage
view.layer.addSublayer(layer)
```

This has the advantage that the shadow is *part of the drawing*, and so there is *no* inefficiency - the very inefficiency you say you are trying to avoid - as there would be if you give the layer itself a shadow and thus compelled the render tree to do the work. Indeed, the same thing is true for the rounded rectangle: it is much more efficient to *draw* a rounded rectangle, as I am doing here, than to force the render tree to round the layer's corners for you, as you are doing.

Comment: And if you don't know how to draw, see my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch15.html